# Deregister the EventHandler in Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am using this piece of code to register the event and want to de-register Event after completing it's task but don't know how to do problem is that I am using local object for registering event..

code..

```
public void loadData()
{
//Here client is loacal object..
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(AccessTokenDownloadCompleted);
}
void AccessTokenDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to remove your event handler after the download is completed. To remove an event handler, all you need to do is:

```
client.DownloadStringCompleted -= new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(AccessTokenDownloadCompleted);
```

Note the `-=` instead of `+=`.

Place this code where the download completes and you should be fine.

Comment: I know this one but problem is that client is local variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
Maybe you can try this:
public void loadData()
{
//Here client is loacal object..
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(AccessTokenDownloadCompleted);
}
void AccessTokenDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Client client = sender as Client;
    if(client != null) 
        client.DownloadStringCompleted -= new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(AccessTokenDownloadCompleted);
}
```